# Store data of a table in Local Storage in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, function, object, local-storage

I use jQuery to create a table with CRUD operations. I give the table the ability to sort and filter data. The sort and filter functions work perfectly as well as all CRUD actions.
I have to store the table's data in local storage. Because of this, I add some codes. It functions and stores the data locally not properly. I need to store properly in array format. I need your assistance to address this issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>CRUD Table jQuery</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row"> 
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-xs-offset-8">
                <input id="searchfield" type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
                <input type="button" id="btnAdd" class="btn btn-primary para" value="Add New" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row pt-3">
            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12 p-2 ">
                <table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr id="headings"> 
                            <th class="num">ID</th>
                            <th class="text">Name</th>
                            <th class="text">Address</th>
                            <th class="num">Age</th>
                            <th class="tdaction">Action</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="searchable"> 
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var emptyNewRow = "<tr class='trNewRow'>"; 
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "<td class='tdID'><input type='text' class='form-control txtID' /></td>";
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "<td class='tdName'><input type='text' class='form-control txtName' /></td>";
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "<td class='tdAddress'><input type='text' class='form-control txtAddress' /></td>";
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "<td class='tdAge'><input type='text' class='form-control txtAge' /></td>";
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "<td class='tdAction'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-success btn-save'> Save</button><button class='btn btn-sm btn-success btn-cancel'> Cancel</button></td>";
        emptyNewRow = emptyNewRow + "</tr>";

        var rowButtons ="<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btn-edit' > Edit </button>  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' > Delete </button>";
        var rowUpdateButtons ="<button class='btn btn-success btn-sm btn-save' > Update </button>  <button class='btn btn-danger btn-sm btn-save' > Delete </button> ";

        $(document).ready(function () {
            
            $("#btnAdd").click(function () { 
                $("#tblData tbody").append(emptyNewRow);
            });
            
            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-save', function () {
                const id =  $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtID").val();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdID").html(""+id+"");

                const name =  $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtName").val();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdName").html(""+name+""); 

                const address =  $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtAddress").val();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAddress").html(""+address+"");

                const age =  $(this).parent().parent().find(".txtAge").val();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAge").html(""+age+"");

                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAction").html(rowButtons);

                //local storage
                let arr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('Data'));
                if(arr==null){
                    let data = ["ID " + id,"NAME "+name,"ADDRESS "+address,"AGE "+ age];
                    localStorage.setItem('Data', JSON.stringify(data));
                }else{
                    arr.push(id,name,address,age);
                    localStorage.setItem('Data',  JSON.stringify(arr));
                }
            });
                        
            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-danger', function () {  
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });
            
            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-cancel', function () { 
                $(this).parent().parent().remove();
            });

            $('#tblData').on('click', '.btn-edit', function () { 

                const id =$(this).parent().parent().find(".tdID").html();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdID").html("<input type='text' value='"+id+"' class='form-control txtID' />"); 

                const name =$(this).parent().parent().find(".tdName").html();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdName").html("<input type='text' value='"+name+"' class='form-control txtName' />"); 

                const address =$(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAddress").html();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAddress").html("<input type='text' value='"+address+"' class='form-control txtAddress' />"); 

                const age =$(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAge").html();
                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAge").html("<input type='text' value='"+age+"' class='form-control txtAge' />"); 

                $(this).parent().parent().find(".tdAction").html(rowUpdateButtons);                               
            });

            //filtering
            $("#searchfield").on("keyup", function() {
                var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
                $("#searchable tr").filter(function() {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
                });
            });

            //sorting
            $('th').each(function (col) {
                $(this).data("type", $(this).attr("class"));

                $(this).click(function () {
                        var type = $(this).data("type");
                        var records = $("table").find("tbody > tr");
                        records.sort(function(x,y){
                            var val1 = $(x).children("td").eq(col).text();
                            var val2 = $(y).children("td").eq(col).text();
                            if (type == "num")
                            {
                                val1 *= 1;
                                val2 *= 1;
                            }
                            return (val1 < val2) ? -1 : (val1 > val2 ? 1 :0)
                        });
                        $.each(records, function(index, row){
                            $("tbody").append(row);
                        });
                });
            }); 
   
        });
    </script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to serialize the whole table content updating the value you have previously saved, you had the option to keep track of changed rows and update only that part of the state. But it would require lots of efforts compared to saving the whole table from scratch and replacing its previously serialized state with the new one.

I focused here on that task only: how to serialize your table in a structured manner, dumping each row as an object having key-values pair as tdClassName-inputValue.

I extrapolated the table you have in your snippet and populated it with some sample data. Then I added a new button that triggers the logic to dump its content inside a variable that will be returned by the `dumpTable()` function.

When you click the button, it will print on console the object containing the table saved state. You can copy that logic in your code so that you'll call that function one moment before replacing the json data in the storage.

```js
function dumpClickHandler() {
  const dataTable = dumpTable();
  console.log(dataTable);
}

function dumpTable() {

  const dataTable = [];

  //fetch table rows and iterate through all of them
  const rows = document.querySelectorAll('#tblData tbody tr');
  for (const row of rows) {
    const dataRow = {};

    //fetch row fields
    const fields = row.querySelectorAll('td');

    //for each field in row
    for (const field of fields) {
      //skip the action field containing buttons
      if (field.classList.contains('tdAction'))
        continue;
      //fetch field name using the class assigned to the table cell
      const fieldName =
        Object.values(field.classList).filter(className => className.startsWith("td"))?.[0];
      //fetch field value
      dataRow[fieldName] = field.querySelector('input')?.value;
    }

    //push the fetched row in the array
    dataTable.push(dataRow);
  }

  return dataTable;
}
```

```css
h1{
  margin: 2rem 0 2rem 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container col-10">

<h1>Table filled with sample data:</h1>

<table id="tblData" class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr id="headings">
      <th class="num">ID</th>
      <th class="text">Name</th>
      <th class="text">Address</th>
      <th class="num">Age</th>
      <th class="tdaction">Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="searchable">
    <tr class="trNewRow">
      <td class="tdID">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtID" value="1">
      </td>
      <td class="tdName">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtName" value="Name1">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAddress">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtAddress" value="Address1">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAge">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtAge" value="10">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAction">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-save">Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="trNewRow">
      <td class="tdID">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtID" value="2">
      </td>
      <td class="tdName">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtName" value="Name2">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAddress">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtAddress" value="Address2">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAge">
        <input type="text" class="form-control txtAge" value="20">
      </td>
      <td class="tdAction">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-save"> Save</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success btn-cancel"> Cancel</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="dumpClickHandler();">DUMP TABLE CONTENT</button>

</div>
```